# Laravel: Historical ranking system with ManyToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to display a page where Users are listed by their Rank. A Rank can have multiple Users (for example, 2 Users can be at the 2nd place) and a User can have multiple Ranks too, because I would like to keep an historic of Users and Ranks through time.

Here's `User.php`

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    // ...

    public function Ranks() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Rank');
    }
}
```

And `Rank.php`

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Rank extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function Users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withPivot('created_at');
    }
}
```

I also have a `rank_user` table in my database, with `id`, `rank_id`, `user_id` and `created_at` fields.

This is how I record it in database:

```php
$user->ranks()->attach($rank_id, ['created_at' => Carbon::now()->addMinutes(105)]);
```

In order to list users by rank, and I mean at the current (most recent) rank, this is what I have:

```php
$ranks = Rank::with('users')->get();
```

For example, for the 1st rank, it gives me all users who have been at the 1st place since the beginning instead of giving me all users who **currently** are at the first place.

I don't know how to limit the query to the most recent date.

Comment: So let's say a user gets to rank 1, but then doesn't play for a year. Should they still be returned along with the other rank 1's who achieved rank 1 more recently?

Comment: hmm, you need to get all ranks, with the last record foreach user using the created_at, i couldnt find the right code till now, this is realy an intresting question

Comment: try this `$rank = App\Rank::with(['users' => function ($query) {
        $query->latest();
    }])->get();`

Comment: @Samsquanch: even if a user doesn't play for a year, a new record is inserted in the `rank_user` table with today's date. So if someone gets more points than the 1st player who didn't played for a year, he will beat him.

@AchrafKhouadja: your code doesn't work because it lists all users who have already been to the 1st Rank, 2nd Rank etc... Check my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked one of my friends and here is the solution we found:

I first have to get the most recent date contained into the `rank_user` pivot table.

```
$date = DB::table('rank_user')->select('created_at')
                              ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                              ->first();
```

Then, I can use `withPivot()` to specify that I want results only for the most recent date we found earlier:

```
$ranks = Rank::with(['users' => function($query) use ($date) {
    $query->wherePivot('created_at', $date->created_at);
}])->get();
```

And voilà ! In that way, I only get the most recent user(s) inside each rank.